# Shift-Z Scaling Issues

Tags: modeling

Whenever I hit shift-z to scale on every axis except the Z, the object scales, but flickers, and whenever I release, it renders. How do I stop this?

Comment: In the 3D view, Shift-Z, when _not_ immediately succeeding a transform key..(G,R, or S) is the default shortcut for going into  rendered view.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to keep pressing shift Z, just press once, release, and scale

Answer (score 0):

hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

This should switch your viewport shading from "rendered" to "solid".

Now select the object with <kbd>RMB</kbd> then hit <kbd>S</kbd> 
and then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

This will scale on all axis except the Z

In Blender the same shortcut can do different things, depending on the previous shortcut used. If you dont hit S before Shift+Z, then you will simply switch the viewport shading from "solid" to "rendered".